# sequelize maximum transactions at one time

Tags: javascript, transactions, promise, sequelize.js

So considering I have a seeder like so:

```
var seedDatabase = function () {
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(createProductTypes());
    promises.push(createCompensationTypes());
    promises.push(createDataSources());
    promises.push(createPeriodsAndStages());
    promises.push(createExportDestinations());

    return Promise.all(promises);
};

function createCompensationTypes() {
    return models.sequelize
        .transaction(
        {
            isolationLevel: models.sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_COMMITTED
        },
        function (q) {
            return models.CompensationType
                .findAll()
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (!result || result.length == 0) {
                        return models.CompensationType
                            .bulkCreate(compensationTypes, { transaction: q })
                            .then(function () {
                                console.log("CompensationTypes created");
                            })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("CompensationTypes seeder skipped, already objects in the database...");
                        return;
                    }
                });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("CompensationTypes seeder finished...");
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("CompensationTypes seeder exited with error: " + error.message);
            return;
        });
};
```

For some reason this hangs on execution. Yet, when I comment any one of the promises added to the array everything goes smoothly as it should.

Also when I do the following in my `seedDatabase` function, it works too:

```
var seedDatabase = function () {
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(createProductTypes());
    promises.push(createDataSources());
    promises.push(createPeriodsAndStages());
    promises.push(createExportDestinations());

    return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        return createCompensationTypes()
    });
};
```

which is bizarre since obviously my code is working but still hangs on an extra promise. Hence my question, is there a maximum of concurrent promises or transactions when using sequelizeJS? Or am I overlooking something else here?

Comment: I guess trying to escape from cb hell you created your own promise hell. It looks like an antipattern to me. Why don't you just use `sequalize.transaction().then( q = > models.CompensationType.findAll()).then(result => whatEver(q)).then( bla => bla*2)`

Comment: The different models are not reliant on each other. I do not want to have a situation that is going to get me 1000 lines of code while the way I'm doing it right now, I have a good sense of what is being inserted just by looking at this one method. I could wrap the transaction around all but then that means, if one fails, all of them do.